# Declare an object called obj1 and method called div(int x, int y). Show how the obj1 will use the method div(int x, int y) to calculate a/b

Tags: java

This is my attempt question is

> Consider two integer variables `a` and `b`. Declare  an  object  called  `obj1`  and  method  called `div(int x, int y)`. Show how the object `obj1` will use the method `div(int x, int y)` to calculate “a /b”.

Please tell me how to fix it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main obj1 = new Main();
        System.out.println("program start");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter A: ");
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter B: ");
        int y = scan.nextInt();

        obj1.div();
        System.out.println("program end");
    }

    public void div(int x, int y) {
        double ans = x/y;
        System.out.println("a/b = " + ans);
    }
}
```

Comment: add param in the method call i.e obj1.div(x, y);

Comment: You don't need to create an object within it's own Class. You can invoke the method within its class's closure by simply calling this( this is an instance of same class). i.e this.div(4,2);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt is almost correct. You must pass the parameters `x` and `y` to `obj1.div()`:

```java
obj1.div(x, y);
```

It's also best practice to return a `double` from `div`, e.g.:

```java
public double div(int x, int y){   
    double ans = x / y;
    return ans;
}
```

and then call it like that:

```
System.out.println("a/b = " + obj1.div(x, y));
```

Answer (score 0):

The method div requires two argumets, x & y. So while invoking the method div, pass two arguments. in your case the two inputs you read from command line, x & y using scanner.

```
obj1.div(x, y);
```